# Get ProcessName from Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In Visual C++, am getting the title of the current window using

```
::GetWindowText(wnd, str, 290);

strcpy(curr_wnd_txt, str);
```

But how can i get the Process Name of the Application for example "Iexplore" for Using Internet Explorer, "Skype" for window with tile "Skype - username", "Explorer" for using windows explorer ?

This is what i tried :

```
void CMainWndDlg::Monitor_ActiveWindowCaptions()
{
    HWND hwnd;
    DWORD process_id=0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &process_id);
    CString strEXEName = GetEXEName (process_id);
}

CString GetEXEName(DWORD dwProcessID)
{
DWORD aProcesses [1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
unsigned int i;

if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
    return "";

cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

TCHAR szEXEName[MAX_PATH];
for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
{
    if (aProcesses [i] == dwProcessID)
    {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                          PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwProcessID);
        if (NULL != hProcess)
        {
            HMODULE hMod;
            DWORD cbNeeded;
            if(EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, 
                                  sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded))
            {
                GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szEXEName, 
                    sizeof(szEXEName)/sizeof(TCHAR));
                return CString (szEXEName);
            }
        }
    }    
}
return "";
}
```

Comment: You can't. Not even Microsoft can. Just start IE and Task Manager. In the "Tasks" tab it shows IE's caption (=web page title) and in the "Processes" it shows IExplore.exe.

Comment: thats wat i need. if i can get process as iexplorer.exe then i could display that as iexplorer easily

Answer (score 1):

GetModuleFileName() can be used to retrieve the path of the executable file of the current process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: that's not probably what's asked here. Its getting the name of the executable from the title of window

Comment: @Aniket: Could be, maybe I should have commented the question and got some clarification. Looking at your answer was useful: I didn't know about GetModuleBaseName().

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enumerate the windows, get the process handle, and then get the name of the executable from the function below.

```
#include "psapi.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")

CString GetEXEName(DWORD dwProcessID)
{
    DWORD aProcesses [1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    //Enumerate all processes
    if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
        return NULL;

    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    TCHAR szEXEName[MAX_PATH];
    //Loop through all process to find the one that matches
    //the one we are looking for
    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
    {
        if (aProcesses [i] == dwProcessID)
        {
            // Get a handle to the process
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                              PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwProcessID);

            // Get the process name
            if (NULL != hProcess)
            {
                HMODULE hMod;
                DWORD cbNeeded;

                if(EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, 
                                      sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded))
                {
                    //Get the name of the exe file
                    GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szEXEName, 
                        sizeof(szEXEName)/sizeof(TCHAR));

                    return CString (szEXEName);
                }
            }
        }    
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Refer here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14843/Finding-module-name-from-the-window-handle

Comment: Am getting error in "return NULL" - more than one constructor applies to convert from int to cstring

Comment: @user1441251 instead of returning `NULL` you can return `""`. The code I've posted compiles with C, but due to strict type checking of C++, the compiler complains of it.

Comment: it worked good but am getting another error "Error 98 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > __thiscall CMainWndDlg::GetEXEName(unsigned long)" (?GetEXEName@CMainWndDlg@@AAE?AV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@K@Z) referenced in function "private: static int __stdcall CMainWndDlg::EnumWindowsProc(struct HWND__ *,long)" (?EnumWindowsProc@CMainWndDlg@@CGHPAUHWND__@@J@Z) C:\Users\logid\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test\MainWnd\MainWndDlg.obj MainWnd
"

Comment: am getting this error when i call CString strEXEName = GetEXEName (process_id);

Comment: Can I see your source code? just this function and the EnumWindow function with how it is defined in CMainWndDlg class?

Comment: @user1441251 with the current code, you may have to use this instead `::GetEXEName(process_id);`

Comment: And not to mention @user1441251 you also need to define GetEXEName() before the definition of the class.