# Get active processname in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Am working on a background appliation in vc++

How can i get the Process Name of the current Application for example "Iexplore" for Using Internet Explorer, "Skype" for window with tile "Skype - username", "Explorer" for using windows explorer ?

i referred this link but am getting Null error :        http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14843/Finding-module-name-from-the-window-handle

Comment: You want the name of the *executable* associated with a particular window handle?

Comment: am getting the full path if i use "char loaded_file_name[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, loaded_file_name, MAX_PATH);"

Comment: i want to get the application name from background, means watever application am using, i should get the exe name

Comment: The article you linked describes exactly what you are asking for. Can you quote your version of the code and annotate where exactly you are getting NULL? And any other debug information, like what you get from `GetLastError` when you get that NULL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ProcessName from Visual C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727124/get-processname-from-visual-c)

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the following code:

```
bool GetActiveProcessName(TCHAR *buffer, DWORD cchLen)
{
    HWND fg = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (fg)
    {
        DWORD pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(fg, &pid);
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
        if (hProcess)
        {
            BOOL ret = QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, buffer, &cchLen);
            //here you can trim process name if necessary
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            return (ret != FALSE);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
if(GetActiveProcessName(buffer, MAX_PATH))
{
    _tprintf(_T("Active process: %s\n"), buffer);
}
else
{
    _tprintf(_T("Cannot obtain active process name.\n"));
}
```

Note though that *QueryFullProcessImageName* function is only available since Windows Vista, on earlier systems you could use *GetProcessImageFileName* (it is similar, but requires linkage with psapi.dll and returns device path instead of usual win32 path)

Answer (score 1):

I used this code in my QT5/C++ project to get the currently active process name and window title successfully, based on some research (thanks @dsi). Just wanted to share the code so that someone else would benefit from it.

```
# Put this two declarations in the top of the CPP file
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
```

And put the following into a method:

```
// get handle of currently active window
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
if (hwnd) {
    // Get active app name
    DWORD maxPath = MAX_PATH;
    wchar_t app_path[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
    if (hProcess) {
        QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, app_path, &maxPath);
        // here you can trim process name if necessary
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        QString appPath = QString::fromWCharArray(app_path).trimmed();
        QFileInfo appFileInfo(appPath);
        windowInfo.appName = appFileInfo.fileName();
    }

    // Get active window title
    wchar_t wnd_title[256];
    GetWindowText(hwnd, wnd_title, sizeof(wnd_title));
    windowInfo.windowTitle = QString::fromWCharArray(wnd_title);
}
```

This code may not be compiled directly, because `windowInfo` is a parameter in my program. Please feel free to let me know in case you encountered any issues when trying this code.