# get process name from visual c++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how to get process information like this format my develop tools is visual c++ 2012 I would like to get process name,process id ,Process Path,Product Name Window Title
but i don't know how to connect those information toghter

This information should change every once i access other applications.

I can get the title of the application, as google- Internet Explorer.
But i cannot get process name as iexplore.

Pls guide me.

[image: img]

Comment: Look at the sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx). It does something somewhat similar.

Comment: this will show all the process as a list if am not wrong. But i need only the current process or application exe name

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get active processname in vc++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745320/get-active-processname-in-vc)

Comment: This is the third time you've asked the same question :(

Comment: yes. I have tried and tried a lot. but am simply missing somewhere that's why

Answer (score 1):

To get the name of the EXE of the current process:

```
TCHAR name[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle(NULL), name, sizeof(name));
```

Using `NULL` as argument to `GetModuleHandle()` will return the `HANDLE` of the EXE used to start the process. The rest is straightforward.

**UPDATE**: From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
TCHAR name[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, name, sizeof(name));
```

You can use `NULL` as the module handle and it will already get the name of the EXE.

Comment: This is giving me the vc++ application exe name... But I want the background application exe name

Comment: @user1441251: That's because you are debugging with the _vshost_ thingy enable. Disable it in the project configuration and it should work as expected.